# SwiftUI: how can to calculate the width of a Text view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, geometryreader, swiftui-text

I have unknown number of Text views I need to account for (as many hours that pass during sleep).  Each Text view is just a single hour e.g. Text("12"), Text("1") etc.

I need to know the width of all the combined hour Text Views so I can subtract from the overall geometry to space accordingly.  The below is a `widthOfString` function that may have worked with UIKit but doesn't seem to calculate the proper size in SwiftUI.  How can I achieve this?

Example usage:

```
  Spacer()
    .frame(width: CGFloat(hourAsDate.timeIntervalSince(hoursBetweenSleepStartAndEnd[(hoursBetweenSleepStartAndEnd.firstIndex(of: hourAsDate) ?? 0) - 1]) / totalSleepSeconds)  * calculateSpaceOfHourText())
  Text("\(calendar.component(.hour, from: hourAsDate))")
    .font(Font.system(size: 13.0))
  Spacer()
    .frame(width: CGFloat(sleepEndDate.timeIntervalSince(hourAsDate) / totalSleepSeconds)  * calculateSpaceOfHourText())
```

My Helper Function and Extension:

```
       //helper
    private func calculateSpaceOfHourText() -> CGFloat {
    
    //The idea here is to try to add up all the space that is taken up by hour Text views and subtract it from the total with of geometry
    
        var hoursToUseForCalculationOfSpace = hoursBetweenSleepStartAndEnd
        
        if hoursBetweenSleepStartAndEnd.first ?? Date() <= sleepStartDate {
            hoursToUseForCalculationOfSpace.removeFirst()
        }
        
        if hoursBetweenSleepStartAndEnd.last ?? Date() >= sleepEndDate {
            hoursToUseForCalculationOfSpace.removeLast()
        }
        return (proxy.size.width - hoursToUseForCalculationOfSpace.map { calendar.component(.hour, from: $0) }.map { "\($0)".widthOfString(usingFont: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: .regular)) }.reduce(0, +))
    }
}

extension String {
   func widthOfString(usingFont font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let fontAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font]
        let size = self.size(withAttributes: fontAttributes)
        //print("THIS width = \(size.width)")
        return size.width
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not direct an answer to your problem, but maybe a direction to look into is the `PreferenceKey` protocol in combination with `GeometryReader`. For example the following code draws a `RoundedRectangle` in the background with the height of the view it modifies:

```
struct HeightPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: [CGFloat] = []
    
    static func reduce(value: inout [CGFloat], nextValue: () -> [CGFloat]) {
        value.append(contentsOf: nextValue())
        
    }
    
    typealias Value = [CGFloat]
}

struct HeightPreferenceViewSetter: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 13)
                .fill(Color.gray)
                .preference(key: HeightPreferenceKey.self,
                            value: [geometry.size.height]) 
              }
    }
}
struct HeightModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .background(HeightPreferenceViewSetter())
            
    }
}
```